# Getting info on objects on linked servers

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have DB2 database linked to my SQL Server.
Is it possible to check indexes on a table in DB2 from MS SQL? How to do that? (mb some sys table or smth)

Comment: FYI, there is no SQL server 18.5. The latest version is 15.0.4043.16, which is 2019 RTM-CU5. I suspect 18.5 is the version of SSMS you are using, which is an IDE used to interact with SQL Server.

Comment: You could query the DB2 catalog views or system tables via the linked server. Added the DB2 tag to your question since the query will be proprietary to that DBMS product.